# What is the depth of an image in Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision

I am learning cs231n Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition. The lecture notes introduce the concepts of width, height, depth. For example,

> In CIFAR-10, images are only of size 32x32x3 (32 wide, 32 high, 3
>   color channels)

However, in another example,

> a volume of size [55x55x96] has 96 depth slices, each of size [55x55]

What does width 96 means? Does it mean 96 color channels? Why can we have more than 3 color channels?

Comment: No, 96 is the number of neurons that are looking 55x55 region in the depth of the input image and generate a feature map. You can say that you have 96 filters applied across the depth of the image and learning some feature maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the number of filters ([a.k.a. kernels, or  feature detector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/188216/12359)) in the previous convolutional layer is 96. You may want to watch the [video](https://youtu.be/LxfUGhug-iQ?t=29m55s) of the lecture, and in particular [this slide](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture7.pdf), which mentions that a filter is applied to the full depth of your previous layer:

[image]